# Installing mod_security on EC2

Tags: php, amazon-ec2, mod-security

I am trying to install mod_security using yum install mod_security but I get this error

```
Loaded plugins: priorities, update-motd, upgrade-helper
amzn-main/latest                                                                           | 2.1 kB     00:00
amzn-updates/latest                                                                        | 2.3 kB     00:00
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package mod_security.x86_64 0:2.7.3-3.23.amzn1 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: httpd-mmn = 20051115 for package: mod_security-2.7.3-3.23.amzn1.x86_64
--> Running transaction check
---> Package httpd.x86_64 0:2.2.27-1.2.amzn1 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: httpd-tools = 2.2.27-1.2.amzn1 for package: httpd-2.2.27-1.2.amzn1.x86_64
--> Running transaction check
---> Package httpd-tools.x86_64 0:2.2.27-1.2.amzn1 will be installed
--> Processing Conflict: httpd24-2.4.9-1.55.amzn1.x86_64 conflicts httpd < 2.4.9
--> Processing Conflict: httpd24-tools-2.4.9-1.55.amzn1.x86_64 conflicts httpd-tools < 2.4.9
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: httpd24 conflicts with httpd-2.2.27-1.2.amzn1.x86_64
Error: httpd24-tools conflicts with httpd-tools-2.2.27-1.2.amzn1.x86_64
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

I already removed httpd24-tools-2.4.9-1.55.amzn1.x86_64 and httpd24-2.4.9-1.55.amzn1.x86_64

Comment: Assume this Amazon Linux. What version of Amazon Linux ?

Comment: @Rico Amazon Linux AMI x86_64 PV EBS

Comment: try `yum install mod24_security.x86_64`

Answer (score 6):

```
sudo yum install mod24_security.x86_64
```

then

```
sudo service httpd restart
```

Answer (score 3):

Got the same error.

Used the below command to remove both apache & tools version 24 and 27.

```
yum remove httpd httpd-tools
```

Then was able to install successfully without any version conflicts
`Check once`.

Comment: if I remove those packages `php56 php56-devel php56-jsonc-devel` get removed also... what's the workaround? trying to install them again bring the conflicts

Comment: I did instead `yum install mod24_security.x86_64`

Answer (score 1):

You can run the command:

```
# yum install mod_security
```

mod_security configuration files:

1)  /etc/httpd/conf.d/mod_security.conf - main configuration file for the mod_security Apache module.

2)  /etc/httpd/modsecurity.d/ - all other configuration files for the mod_security Apache.

3)  /etc/httpd/modsecurity.d/modsecurity_crs_10_config.conf - Configuration contained in this file should be customized for your specific requirements before deployment.

4)  /var/log/httpd/modsec_debug.log - Use debug messages for debugging mod_security rules and other problems.

5)  /var/log/httpd/modsec_audit.log - All requests that trigger a ModSecurity events (as detected) or a serer error are logged ("RelevantOnly") are logged into this file.

For more information check out this article on how to set it up o CentoOS:
http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/rhel-fedora-centos-httpd-mod_security-configuration/